# Why addiing css classes through string concatenation via conditions can be bad?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am reading the following documentation https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/class-name-manipulation.html, as they have mentioned.

```
render: function() {
  var classString = 'message';
  if (this.props.isImportant) {
    classString += ' message-important';
  }
  if (this.props.isRead) {
    classString += ' message-read';
  }
  // 'message message-important message-read'
  return <div className={classString}>Great, I'll be there.</div>;
}
```

*This can quickly get tedious, as assigning class name strings can be hard to read and error-prone. classSet() solves this problem:*

I don't understand it, I mean I use the pattern in my code ,what they have mentioned as a bad practice. Why it is? what can go wrong?

Comment: You have to type the spaces, and you can forget and mess things up. It can be a hard bug to track down when it happens.

Comment: I think the quote `This can quickly get tedious, as assigning class name strings can be hard to read and error-prone` answers your question. It is probably fine for one or two tags, but more than that would quickly become a nightmare to maintain. Plus you have to make sure that every string is properly formatted or you'll be chasing errors for hours.

Comment: so the entire classNames or classSet solves the problem of spaces?

Comment: [classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) would be useful here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's bad practice for the reasons @yu_ominae mentioned. Using classSet() fixes the lack of clarity in the code, but it requires you to use React with Addons over vanilla React. If you need to worry about bandwidth for your site, this might not be the best idea considering React alone is rather large. What you could do is something like this:

```
render: function () {
        var classes = ['message'];
        if (this.props.isImportant) classes.push('message-important');
        if (this.props.isRead) classes.push('message-read');

        return <div className={classes.join(' ')}>Great, I'll be there.</div>;
}
```

I think this should be less error-prone than what you wrote and a little bit easier to read. If you'd rather use classSet() instead, then that would work as well.